# StreamingSubscritionConnection throwing Key not found exception

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am developing an application which uses the StreamingSubscriptionConnection object in the EWS managed API.

When the network connection is lost for a certain period of time it throws an exception whose StackTrace shows this

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.StreamingSubscriptionConnection.IssueSubscriptionFailures(GetStreamingEventsResponse gseResponse)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.StreamingSubscriptionConnection.HandleServiceResponseObject(Object response)
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingServiceRequestBase.ParseResponses(Object state)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException:
```

Anyone has any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your client receives notification for a subscriptons which has already been terminated and removed from the client. The StreamingSubscriptionConnection class maintains an internal list of subscriptions. When it receives a failure event from the server, it notifies the client and removes the subscription from said list. If it receives another failure event for this subscription the exception you are seeing would be created.

To troubleshoot the issue try monitor the traffic returned between your client and the Exchange server with Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It acts as a proxy between your application and Exchange and it can decrypt SSL traffic. Perhaps this will give you more insight about what's going on.